# Multi select check box with index

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have a multi-select checkbox as shown below. On this method `getMultiSelectedItems()` which retrieves the selected items as shown below. Let's say I have selected one item.

```
checked:true,
display: "Co-sleep with parent(s)",
encode : "1",
label :  "uiCoSleepNight"
```

Can you tell me how to include the `index` of the item being selected on above object? We can consider `index` as the order of `inputs` array.

**Note:** Actually, I need the `index` of the selected item.Hope there is a way to modify `getMultiSelectedItems()` to get that. In other words `index` of the `array` which user has selected.

**.html**

```
<ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let i of inputs">
          <ion-label>{{i.display}}</ion-label>
          <ion-checkbox name="{{i.label}}" [(ngModel)]="i.checked"></ion-checkbox>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
```

**.ts**

```
 //get Multi Selected Items
  getMultiSelectedItems(): any {
    return this.inputs.filter(opt => opt.checked);
  }

    this.inputs= [
        {
            "encode": "1",
            "display": "Own bed/crib in own room",
            "label": "uiOwnRoomOwnBedNight",
            "checked": false
        },
        {
            "encode": "1",
            "display": "Own bed/crib but share room with sibling(s)",
            "label": "uiSharedRoomOwnBedNight",
            "checked": false
        },
        {
            "encode": "1",
            "display": "Own bed/crib but share room with parent(s)",
            "label": "uiParentRoomOwnBedNight",
            "checked": false
        },
        {
            "encode": "1",
            "display": "Co-sleep with parent(s)",
            "label": "uiCoSleepNight",
            "checked": false
        },
    ],
```

Comment: I'm confused about `Can you tell me how to include the index of the item is being selected on above object?` can you explaim more?

Comment: Actually, I need the `index` of the `selected item`.Hope there is a way to modify `getMultiSelectedItems()` to get that. In other words `index` of the `array` which user has selected. @Pengyy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second value you can get in filter is index.

```
return this.inputs.filter((opt, i) => {
    if(opt.checked) {opt.index = i; return true;}
        });
```

Comment: Exactly what I need.Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Hope I have get your opinion. you can use `Array.map` to generate a new `array` with the result of the `Array.filter` which contains the original data and its index from the original array.

```js
function getMultiSelectedItems() {
  var arr = [];
  return this.inputs.filter(opt => opt.checked)
                    .map(item => {return {"index": inputs.indexOf(item), "data": item};});
}

var inputs = [{
    "encode": "1",
    "display": "Own bed/crib in own room",
    "label": "uiOwnRoomOwnBedNight",
    "checked": false
  },
  {
    "encode": "1",
    "display": "Own bed/crib but share room with sibling(s)",
    "label": "uiSharedRoomOwnBedNight",
    "checked": true
  },
  {
    "encode": "1",
    "display": "Own bed/crib but share room with parent(s)",
    "label": "uiParentRoomOwnBedNight",
    "checked": false
  },
  {
    "encode": "1",
    "display": "Co-sleep with parent(s)",
    "label": "uiCoSleepNight",
    "checked": true
  },
];

console.log(getMultiSelectedItems());
```

or simply you can use `Array.indexOf` with the result of `Array.filter`, but keep in mind that this won't work if the instance of the object(element of Array.filter) is changed.

```js
function getMultiSelectedItems() {
  return this.inputs.filter(opt => opt.checked);
}

var inputs = [{
    "encode": "1",
    "display": "Own bed/crib in own room",
    "label": "uiOwnRoomOwnBedNight",
    "checked": false
  },
  {
    "encode": "1",
    "display": "Own bed/crib but share room with sibling(s)",
    "label": "uiSharedRoomOwnBedNight",
    "checked": true
  },
  {
    "encode": "1",
    "display": "Own bed/crib but share room with parent(s)",
    "label": "uiParentRoomOwnBedNight",
    "checked": false
  },
  {
    "encode": "1",
    "display": "Co-sleep with parent(s)",
    "label": "uiCoSleepNight",
    "checked": true
  },
];

getMultiSelectedItems().forEach(item => console.log(inputs.indexOf(item)));
```

Comment: I have tried your first solution.But it is not working :( Always `undefined`.

Comment: @Sampath by `not working`, means errors? or new issues?

Comment: It returns `undefined`.Anyway, the other user's solution is working.Thanks for your support :)

Comment: @Sampath ok, if you don't mind adding new property to original data , misha130's answer is good to go.